# Image widget stopped working after core update

Tags: ajax

I recently did a long overdue update from 7.20 to 7.33.

However, after I've made the update, the "Image" widget has stopped working when trying to edit content through the admin screen. I cannot add or remove any images using this widget - it makes an AJAX call and the request comes back as 200, but the image upload/removal fails without an error.

I think it's a problem with the AJAX but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - the AJAX form was not being cached by memcache, and so it was failing out every single time. Restarting memcache did the trick.

Comment: If you select your answer as the correct one this issue will no longer show up in the unanswered questions list (and you get points).